# Javascript read special characters from file

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a little problem with some code. I'm trying to read a file and display its content in a textarea, my problem is that is a text in Spanish which means it includes a lot of special accent characters ***ó/ú/í/é/á*** which channot be read and appear as "?"

[image]

My code for reading the document is the following

```
            var read = new XMLHttpRequest();
            read.open('GET', url, true);

            read.onreadystatechange=function(){                    
                document.getElementById("textLecture").innerHTML=read.response;
            }
            read.send();
```

Any tips or suggestions on what could I do?

Comment: Fix the encoding on the server side.

Comment: What if the file I'm reading is a local file? should I still send it server side then send it back?

Comment: What do you mean by "local file"? How do you read it using XHR? In what environment does this script run? Regardless, you should fix the encoding.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that then, and I sort of got confused, this is going to be for web, but then my files are going to be on the server anyway. Thanks for your reply :)